# YouTube Java API vs Android REST Client implementation

Tags: android, youtube-api, atom-feed

I am trying to make an Android app which will pull uploaded videos from a channel and display them in a list view. Users will be able to watch videos, subscribe to the channel, comment, and like videos.

I have looked at using an Atom feed to get the video info from YouTube (I have a working app), but I came across the Java API for YouTube today, which abstracts all the parsing that's needed, if I implement the REST client code myself.

My question is which is the recommended solution for this? And which will perform better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for sure " **DON'T INVENT THE WHEEL !** "

I build smaller application for android and believe me using YouTube API is much ***better*** than anything else.

if you are seeking to play videos inside your Application try to see also Open-Youtube-player!

also you should use the API for other features and for its *performance* you don't need to add more *leakage* to your application you need it fast and light.